# Discord bypasses hosts file, Windows firewall and Router firewall rules to download Tenor gifs

Tags: networking, firewall, discord

I would like to prevent Tenor gif reactions from showing on Discord.

Discord offering no way of doing that locally, I attempted to completely block all traffic to and from tenor.com and tenor.co. All attempts have failed.

Hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1       tenor.com
127.0.0.1       tenor.co
127.0.0.1       151.101.194.217
127.0.0.1       151.101.66.217
127.0.0.1       151.101.2.217
127.0.0.1       151.101.130.217
```

I created Windows firewall rules to block inbound and outbound connections to the 4 IP addresses above for all programs on the computer.

On my router running DD-WRT, I added the following rules :

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 151.101.194.217 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 151.101.194.217 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 151.101.66.217 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 151.101.66.217 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 151.101.2.217 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 151.101.2.217 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 151.101.130.217 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 151.101.130.217 -j DROP
```

In addition to that, I added tenor.co and tenor.com to the Access Restrictions panel, under "Website Blocking by URL Address".

Seeing as Discord still managed to download gifs (really they are mp4 videos) despite all these rules being in place *at the same time*, I opened Wireshark to look at the actual traffic and it would appear that the gifs are coming through Cloudflare or Amazon CDNs.

How would I go about blocking this kind of traffic and isn't this practice of bypassing all these restrictions to download third party content unsafe?

Comment: It's not really "bypassing" anything. You made an assumption about where the files are coming from and it was wrong. Nothing more, nothing less. It's only logical to use (separate) CDNs for high-volume traffic like this.

Comment: It was not an assumption. In the console (ctrl+shift+i, same as chrome) the request URL of the files is either tenor.com or tenor.co.